# Why my JOIN is showing double results?

Tags: mysql, sql

So this is what my query looks like, but its producing double results. I am newbie to SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_projects p, tbl_issues i WHERE p.admin_id = 3
```

Comment: Try with the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: You need `join` conditions.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're joining in an old style, without join conditions, so you get a cartesian product. Please use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT   * -- It is recommended to explicitly select the attributes you need
FROM     tbl_projects p
JOIN     tbl_issues i -- I assumed inner join
      ON p.id = i.project_id -- You'll have to figure out the conditions yourself
WHERE    p.admin_id = 3
```

Comment: I guess `ON p.admin_id = i.admin_id` just to be sure :-)

Comment: @Alex I don't think so, I would expect something like `ON p.id = i.project_id`. Put the point is I don't know, so what point would be served by guessing. Leave something for OP :P (still edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JOIN query, and you're not using the table "tbl_issues" anywhere

Comment: It is a join query, in pre ANSI-92 syntax. OP is using `tbl_issues`, because (s)he selects `*`